# Is it haram to pick up an object from a loved place

Tags: halal-haram

Is it haram to pick up objects from a certain place so it can remind you of it? For example, picking up a leaf or a rose from a place that you like. I live next to a park and in front of the sign I picked up a rock to bring back home with me for fun, i am fully aware that nothing can protect me but Allah (swt) and only brought it to remind me of the park, is this haram?

Comment: The answers seem to think this question is about theft, but my impression is that it is really asking about a form of idolatry.  The Question should make it clear exactly what it is that might be considered haram.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because like you mentioned you got a rock from a public park, whatever’s in that park is available to the general public. Obviously that doesn’t mean vandalizing a park is okay, but things like flowers, stones, etc. that are from the park isn’t considered stealing. Sure, if it was part of a fancy display or part of someone’s property, that would be haram. But since it’s a park that’s available to the public, taking a small stone from it wouldn’t really affect anything since it’s just an everyday object found lying on the ground anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of **public** items/properties is *similar* to the **private** items/properties. Both you cannot take without a permission, unless it is well-known/established among people that the thing you've taken from public has no monetary value at all, by constitution or by the tradition in that particular community.

[Reference](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/288543/she-visited-a-garden-in-a-foreign-country-and-took-some-cuttings-from-a-tree-to-plant-them-in-her-country-is-this-regarded-as-stealing)